# Rendering Razor pages to html requires different models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I use this method to render views to html (which is required for generating pdfs).

```
public static class ControllerContextExtensions
{
    public static string RenderViewToHtml(this ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
    {
        context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context,
                                                            viewName);

            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, context.Controller.ViewData, context.Controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            string html = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);
            html = Regex.Replace(html, "<head>", string.Format("<head><base href=\"{0}\" />", baseUrl), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return html;
        }
    }
```

However, when I changed model in view, it always fails (at `Render(viewContext, sw);` with phrase 'It requires model A, but passed model is of type B', even though partial view has declared model of type B. 
Note: "ABC" partial view has `@model InvoiceReportModelItem` in it
[image: picture one] 
As an experiment, I have passed empty model of BaseReportViewModel descendant  type. Now it says it requires model of type which I tried to pass previously.
[image]

What can be the cause of the problem? I have tried to rename the file (maybe dictionary is cached or something but it didnt help)

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking but you could use a model that contains multiple models inside.

Comment: @Danieboy, the problem is that the view doesn't accept any of models it asks for, neither descendant of BaseReportViewModel (wrong) nor InvoiceReportModelItem (declared as Model of "ABC" view)

Comment: what is the model specified in **abc** view ?

Comment: @Danieboy please check messages of exceptions again, they are mutually exclusive

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I have already mentioned, "ABC" partial view has model InvoiceReportModelItem in it

Comment: `InvoiceReportModelItem model = new InvoiceReportModel()` should work

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thats impossible, `InvoiceReportModelItem` and `InvoiceReportViewModel : BaseReportViewModel` are different types

Comment: then how you suppose these two work, both are different types, the type defined in your view should be the type passed from controller to view

Comment: Your view can have `BaseReportViewModel` and then pass to it object of child class like: `BaseReportViewModel vm  = new InvoivceReportViewModel();`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Check message of exceptions on screenshots again, you didnt undestand what I am asking for. Check again messages of exceptions and have in mind that 'ABC' view has InvoiceReportModelItem as model and what happens (! thats the problem) when I pass model of this type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was not in this view, but in its layout view model which was different... Yea, 'partial with layout', I know.

In my case view had `InvoiceReportModelItem` type of model, and its Layout - `BaseReportViewModel`.

Comment: Please provide better context with this answer, how did you solve it?

Comment: @Daniel My partial view was providing Layout = "/path/to/layout", which had different view model (viewmodel type in partial view != viewmodel type in layout view). I didn't notice that because thrown error does not show were inconsistency is, it just says the model is wrong.